# Installation directory for internal scripts

Tags: linux, file-structure

In GNU/Linux the recommended installation directory for internal binaries of a given package is `/usr/lib` or `/usr/libexec`. However, I can't find any recommendation for internal (non-binary) executable scripts. Should they also go in the mentioned directories? Wouldn't `/usr/share` make more sense since they are architecture independent?